# MVVMHelpers AsyncCommand await doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm implementing a Xamarin.Forms Application using the MVVMHelpers Nuget: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers

I try to use the AsyncCommand from this library which is described in this Blog: https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command

I want that the following chain to be implemented:

1. The User clicks on Upload Button
2. Upload Dialog opens and the User choose a file
3. The File Text is prompted to a richTextEdit

To handle this i'm using the following ViewModel:

```
    public class UploadViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string[] _allowedFileTypes;
    private string _fileText;
    private bool _hasFile;

    public AsyncCommand UploadFileCommand { get; private set; }

    public string FileText { get { return _fileText; } set { SetProperty(ref _fileText, value); } }

    public bool HasFile { get { return _hasFile; } set { SetProperty(ref _hasFile, value); } }

    public UploadViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Upload";
        _allowedFileTypes = new string[] { "txt" };
        UploadFileCommand = new AsyncCommand(UploadFileAsync, x => IsNotBusy);
    }

    private async Task UploadFileAsync()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;            

        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(_allowedFileTypes);

            if (fileData == null)
                return;

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileData.GetStream());
            FileText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            HasFile = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileText);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

> Notice the BaseViewModel is from MVVMHelpers

My problem is that in async Method `UploadFileAsync` the `isBusy = false` is reached before the work is done. So I think it's problem of my async/await understanding. I read several Blogs and Answers on Stackoverflow, but don't get it. Also tried to run the `GetStream()` in an own Task but with the same result.

UPDATE: The view in Xamarin.Forms XAML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:UploadViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <button:SfButton Text="Upload File" Command="{Binding UploadFileCommand}" IsVisible="{Binding IsNotBusy}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
        <richTextEditor:SfRichTextEditor IsVisible="{Binding HasFile}" Text="{Binding FileText}" ReadOnly="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ShowToolbar="False"/>
        <busyindicator:SfBusyIndicator x:Name="busyindicator" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" AnimationType="DoubleCircle"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: I wanted to help you and made a minimum reproducible example [here](https://github.com/Leander-van-Boven/TestConsoleCSharp). Initially I was able to simulate your problem, however at some point this stopped, sadly I can't remember what I did. Maybe you can use it?

Comment: Hey @Leander thank you for the example. You using async methods without awaiting them and without returning a task. As far as I know this is bad practice. I think in your case everything runs synchronous and that’s why it’s working. In my case I’m using a Loading Animation on the UI which would freeze if my code runs without await.

Comment: Are you sure the code posted reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi @StephenCleary i added the view Layout. This reproduces the issue for sure.I'm using syncfusion Components but you should be able to replace this by simple Button.

Comment: @Sebi Although I was convinced my code was already async, I have changed it slightly, and now `PollBusy` definitely isn't synchronous anymore. Again `finally` is executed after the `try` block. Maybe you can post a MVCE as well?

Comment: Where is `IsBusy` defined?

Comment: @StephenCleary It's defined in the BaseViewModel. The BaseViewModel comes from the MVVMHelpers Library. There is the AsyncCommand defined as well.

Comment: Is it possible that something else is setting it to `false`?

Comment: I don't think so because this is the complete ViewModel which is just bound to this View. There is no more code which access this.